# How to validate dropdown fields in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden type text box. I just got the name of the textbox and set it as the id of the dropdown down.

Now I need to validate the dropdown. This is what I have done.

```
     <input type="hidden" value="100" name="test1_season_1">

    $('input[value="100"][type="hidden"]').each(function(){
         myString = $(this).attr('name');

         $("#formId").validate({
            rules: {
                myString: "required",
                },
             messages: {
                 mystring: "<br>Please select from dropdown.",       
             }
         });
    });
```

But the validation message is not showing.

So i directly gave the textbox name and check for the validation, this time it works.

```
         $("#formId").validate({
            rules: {
                test1_season_1: "required",
                },
             messages: {
                 test1_season_1: "<br>Please select from dropdown.",       
             }
         });
```

My problem is, each time the textbox name will be dynamically generated, so i can't give it directly. I have to generate two dropdowns if there exists two hidden type text box.

Please help me no this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the value of a variable as a key for setting a property when initialising an object (in that manner, anyway). The syntax for initialising an object will accept keys without quotes, so what you're actually saying is create a property with the key `myString`, and what you wanted was to create a property with the key being the value of your `myString` variable.

Try the following instead:

```
myString = $(this).attr('name');
alert(correctString); // not entirely sure about this line - where does correctString come from?

var rules = {};
rules[myString] = "required";

var messages = {};
messages[myString] = "<br>Please select from dropdown.";

$("#formId").validate({
    rules: rules,
    messages: messages
});
```

Instead of calling `.validate()` for each hidden input, you could instead create two objects with all the rules and messages, then call `.validate()` a single time:

```
var rules = {};
var messages = {};

$('input[value="100"][type="hidden"]').each(function() {
    myString = $(this).attr('name');
    rules[myString] = 'required';
    messages[myString] = '<br>Please select from dropdown.';
});

$("#formId").validate({
    rules: rules,
    messages: messages
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help(Please ignore alert(correctString);). The above code works fine if there is only one dropdown, but if have two dropdowns the error message was shown only for one dropdown.

Comment: @saran The first thing I'd look at is whether or not calling `.validate()` on an element multiple times overrides rules set by the previous calls. Since I don't use any validation plugins myself, or know specifically which plugin you're using (link to the documentation for your specific plugin would be useful) I can't help you much more yet.

Comment: The plugin version is jQuery validation plug-in 1.5.5

Comment: @saran I've edited the answer to include an extra bit of code which calls `.validate()` a single time; I'm not sure if that's going to help but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Give the inputs a `class` and use the Class Rules

```
$.validator.addClassRules("myvalidator", { 
   required: true, 
   message: "<br>Please select from dropdown." 
});

<input type="hidden" value="100" class="myvalidator" name="test1_season_2">
<input type="hidden" value="100" class="myvalidator" name="test1_season_3">
<input type="hidden" value="100" class="myvalidator" name="test1_season_999">
```

[Docs for `addClassRules` here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules)